# Docker RUN: failed to resolve process when trying to build a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile with below content:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# working directory 
WORKDIR /opt

# create directory for gatling install
RUN mkdir -p dir

# install
RUN apk add --update wget bash libc6-compat && \
mkdir -p /tmp/downloads && \
wget -q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip && \
mkdir -p /tmp/archive && \
cd /tmp/archive && \
unzip /tmp/downloads/file.zip && \
mv /tmp/archive/file/* /opt/file/ && \
rm -rf /tmp/*

# change context to file directory
WORKDIR  /opt/file

# set directories below to be mountable from host
VOLUME ["/opt/file/conf", "/opt/file/results", "/opt/file/user-files"]

# set environment variables
ENV PATH /opt/path
ENV HOME /opt/HOME

ENTRYPOINT ["execScript.sh"]
```

When I run this command : `sudo docker build -t tag:name .` I got below error as:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "RUN apk add --update wget bash libc6-compat && \
mkdir ..." did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
```

I'm using Mac M1 Apple chip, arm64. How do I resolve this issue?

Edited: I tweak a bit by adding `RUN` to each line, it turns out that the faulty line was `wget -q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip`, logging was:

```
Dockerfile:22
--------------------
  20 |     RUN apk add --update wget bash libc6-compat
  21 |     RUN mkdir -p /tmp/downloads 
  22 | >>> RUN wget -q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip
  23 |     RUN mkdir -p /tmp/archive 
  24 |     RUN cd /tmp/archive
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c wget -q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
```

Further debugging by jumping directly to docker using `docker exec -it id sh`, I get this error when re-run the whole command:

```
/bin/sh -c wget -q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip
```

Turns out that wget cannot detect whole part `-q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip` in its command, I have tried to put this wget command into double ticks, but no use.
How do I disable `/bin/sh -c` ?

Comment: Error 139 is a segmentation fault.  Try doing `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain sudo docker build -t tag:name .` to get the log in a simpler format that might let you see what causes it.

Comment: ```1.220 (9/9) Installing wget (1.20.3-r0)
1.249 Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
1.252 OK: 111 MiB in 61 packages
1.686 Segmentation fault```
@HansKilian could you take a look

Comment: Keep in in mind that the base image is five years old. Are you sure you want to use such an outdated image?

Comment: @NicoHaase currently I just want to do a demo before I can update its version, so yeah...

Comment: Like Nico, I suspect that your problem may be related to the age of the image. I've been trying to find a different image you can use. Can you try switching to `openjdk:19-jdk-alpine` to see if that fixes it? That's the newest Alpine image I could find. The latest versions of the JDK aren't available in an Alpine version. Also, the OpenJDK images look like they're deprecated according to https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Comment: @HansKilian I have tweaked a bit and figured out the ```wget``` line was the issue, but try ```verbose``` only show that connected successfully, nothing else, can you have a look at this? 
the jdk still work, but yeah I will change the version once this get through

Comment: Why not split up the lines to debug this further? What do you mean by "nothing else"? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated the question, please see it.

Comment: "wget cannot read the flag" - what does that mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase wget cannot be executed, sorry for bad English. wget cannot detect the params follow in command line. ```-q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip``` this part is not detected.

Comment: "cannot detect URL" - what does that mean? Are you facing any error message that you could share? Also, as far as I see, this problem is still not related to programming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257282/discussion-between-tringuyen-and-nico-haase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem comes from using Mac Apple chip, changed to a Window PC using same Dockerfile built with no issue.
Only updated openjdk:19-alpine, but 8-alpine still works!

Answer (score -4):

You have a spaces after the slashes, remove them.

**UPDATE:** was checking with mobile and it showed space after the `&& \` on the line endings, this is a common mistake that results in this kind of error.

Checking on desktop I see no space and any problem with the commands but it is better to start with separate RUN commands so you can identify the specific command that is erroring, so in your case you should start with

```
RUN apk add --update wget bash libc6-compat
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/downloads
RUN wget -q -O /tmp/downloads/file.zip https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/file.zip
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/archive
RUN cd /tmp/archive && unzip /tmp/downloads/file.zip
RUN mv /tmp/archive/file/* /opt/file/
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*
```

And if all is good then concatenate the commands.

Comment: I don't have any space, only breakline, does that affect the script ?

Comment: After which slashes? What makes you think that this leads to the given error message?

Comment: Your "update" effectively invalidates the answer and renders it useless. Also invalid line continuation would have resulted in conceptually different error, definitely not a segfault. Consider deleting it.